# can we make class that contain main method anonymous

Tags: java

Below is example of anonymous inner class in this we make anonymous class with A

```
class A
{
    void one()
    {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}

class One
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new A()
        {
            void five()
            {
                one();
            }
        }.five();
    }
}
```

My question is can we make class `One` as anonymous (not its inner anonymous class) i.e. simply class that contain **public static void main** method.

Comment: Did you try it? Does it compile when you do this? More importantly, does it run?

Comment: Your question is really unclear. `One` is a top-level class; anonymous classes are always nested ones... what are you really trying to achieve, anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`static void main(String...)` must be `static` and inner classes (anonymous or otherwise) cannot have static methods.

On Nested classes vs inner classes http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

> Nested classes are divided into two categories: static and non-static. Nested classes that are declared static are simply called static nested classes. Non-static nested classes are called inner classes.

Comment: How to do it can u please explain sir?

Comment: I thought you could, but you can't.

Comment: Google disagrees ;) https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=inner+class+cannot+have+static+methods

Comment: @PeterLawrey You're perfectly right and thanks for the link precising the terminology (nested class vs inner class). Have an upvote !

Comment: @dystroy I don't like to be perdantic but in this case, anonymous classes are treated as inner classes even in a static context. :|

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create static methods for anonymous classes. In the first instance you would not be able to refer to the static method. The only possible way would be through reflections at runtime (hardly good coding practice). In the second instance all anonymous and inner classes are created with some "parent" instance (in your example your anonymous instance of A will contain a reference to an instance of One). The implication is that inner and anonymous classes are not designed with static methods in mind. If they do need static methods then they should be part of the parent class.